# Date populate until next date value encountered R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset with date values like this.

```
      Date        Id
      10/1/2013   3444
                  87873
                  1243
                  35473
                  7363
                  8335 
      10/2/2013   4783
                  3355
                  4544
                  94453
                  33554
```

What I am trying to do is automatically populate the date values until the next date value is encountered, Oct 1 2013 should be populated until Oct 2 2013 is encountered. The final dataset should look like this

```
      Date        Id
      10/1/2013   3444
      10/1/2013   87873
      10/1/2013   1243
      10/1/2013   35473
      10/1/2013   7363
      10/1/2013   8335 
      10/2/2013   4783
      10/2/2013   3355
      10/2/2013   4544
      10/2/2013   94453
      10/2/2013   33554
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could try `na.locf` from `zoo` after changing the `''` values to `NA`.

```
library(zoo)
is.na(df1$Date) <- df1$Date==''
df1$Date <- na.locf(df1$Date)
```

Or using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), for the grouping variable (`cumsum(Date!='')`), we assign (`:=`) 'Date' as the first element of 'Date' (`Date[1L]`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Date:= Date[1L] , cumsum(Date!='')]
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("10/1/2013", "", "", "", "", "", 
 "10/2/2013", 
 "", "", "", ""), Id = c(3444L, 87873L, 1243L, 35473L, 7363L, 
 8335L, 4783L, 3355L, 4544L, 94453L, 33554L)), .Names = c("Date", 
 "Id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: @akrun great solution! I was struggling with this problem for a while ! thanks